# Switch remote branch in Git

Tags: git, branch

Is it possible to switch to different remote branch without cloning it?

In remote I have multiple branches

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/clay
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/stand
```

I cloned `clay` branch and working on it. Now I want to work on `master` branch. How can I switch to it?

Comment: `git checkout master`?

Comment: git checkout origin master

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't clone a **branch** you clone the complete repository and connect local branches with remote branches. The best way is to make a local branch.

```
git branch master -t origin/master
```

with that line you can connect the local branch **master** with the remote branch **master** if it's not present at that time. Then you can checkout and switch that branch.

Normally the master branch is available and you can switch with checkout to the other branch with **checkout**.

```
git checkout newbranch
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a tracking branch. This can be done by the following command.

```
git branch --track origin/your_branch
```

This will create a tracking branch for you locally. You just have to clone the repo. There is no such thing as cloning a branch. You just track a branch.